# Gesture Detector with onDraw() called multiple times

Tags: android, gesture

I am using `GestureDetector` to identify the touch.I have two `Relative layouts`of same layout  size.I am trying to draw an image A on one layout and move an image B(created using `onDraw`) on another layout.While I move my image B I am using `GestureDetector` to identify the touch.When I move my image B, image A(view) `onDraw()` method  is called multiple times. Please help me to avoid calling `onDraw()` multiple times.Here is my code

```
public class TouchExampleActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout r1;
RelativeLayout r2;
Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context = TouchExampleActivity.this;
    r1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.r1);
    r2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.r2);

    TouchExampleView view = new TouchExampleView(this);

    DrawCircle drawCircle = new DrawCircle(context);

    r1.addView(view);
    r2.addView(drawCircle);

}

class DrawCircle extends View {

    Paint p;

    public DrawCircle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        p = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Log.v("Touch", "Called Draw Circle");
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(60, 50, 50, p);

    }
}

}
```

TouchExampleView.java

```
public class TouchExampleView extends View {
private Drawable mIcon;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;
static boolean fStartDrag = false;
static boolean fDrag = false;
private float ypos = 40;
private float xpos = 30;
public static float sx, sy;

private VersionedGestureDetector mDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public TouchExampleView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public TouchExampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TouchExampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());

    mDetector = VersionedGestureDetector.newInstance(context, new GestureCallback());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, 0);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}

private class GestureCallback implements VersionedGestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    public void onDrag(float dx, float dy) {



        if ((dx == -1) && (dy == -1)) {

            fStartDrag = true;
            fDrag = false;
        }

        else if (fStartDrag) {

            if (dy >= mPosY && dy <= ypos + mPosY && dx >= mPosX && dx <= mPosX + xpos) {

                fDrag = true;
                fStartDrag = false;
            }
        } else if (fDrag) {
            System.out.println("fDrag");
            if (mPosX < 3)
                mPosX = 3;
            else if (mPosX > 400)
                mPosX = 400;
            else

                mPosX = dx;

            // mPosY = dy;

            postInvalidate();
        }
    }

    public void onScale(float scaleFactor) {
        mScaleFactor *= scaleFactor;


        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));


        postInvalidate();
    }
}

}
```

My sample xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android1:id="@+id/r1"
    android1:layout_width="620dip"
    android1:layout_height="320dip"
    android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android1:layout_marginBottom="94dp" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android1:id="@+id/r2"
    android1:layout_width="620dip"
    android1:layout_height="320dip"
    android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android1:layout_marginBottom="94dp" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I use two relative layouts of different size and position then it works fine, `onDraw()` is not called multiple times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying so much I found this answer to my question.`setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` prevents calling `onDraw()` multiple times.Its working for me.I hope I am going right.

```
   View circleView;
   r2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.r2);
   circleView= r2;         
   circleView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I has many unnecessary drawing operation. This awesome note removes all of them. Thank you